# How to give a some Data from a site and show that on my site

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

i was search in the Internet but don't find Good Reference .
Target Website have a WebForm (Without Captcha) , i want to Show The Result of That WebForm on my Website.

My Target isn't Google.com , but Like This

Example : Create a Form on My Site , and The Result of My Form Shows The Query on Google.com (just The Result of Search on Google.com) <-- Example

Comment: Google has [an API](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) to add custom search, and so do many other major web services. If you need to scrape a site that doesn't offer such a service, the question is much too broad to answer.

Comment: And what's with the Random Capitalization?

Comment: i don't want it for Google , i Say Google For Example

Comment: @M.Shokouhi - WhEn yoU caPiTaliZe raNdoMly, yOu mAkE Yourself lOok liKe YoU're wrItiNg a raNsOm NotE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to display data from another site on your site, you'll need to utilize that site/service's API ([Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)). Following your example of displaying data from a Google's search, you would use Google's [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/dev_guide.html). If you have a question about embedding data from a specific site or service on your site, you should probably ask a separate question on StackOverflow, detailing your intended usage.